# Laravel retrieves too many model on a simple paginate query with loaded relations

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a simple database with couple of tables. **orders** - the main table, about 16_000 records. Each order has payments. The **order_payments** table is about 17_000 records. Also each could have zero or more travellers in a **order_tourists** table - 33_000 rows.

The Order model looks like this

```
namespace App;

class Order extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{
    public function payments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\OrderPayment');
    }

    public function tourists()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\OrderTourist');
    }
}
```

I have a simple task to display a paginated list of all orders. Each item in this list should display some order's information (from the **orders** table), the sum of all payments and names of all travellers.

The first that came to my mind was something like this.

Get all orders with payments and travellers and pass this data to a view

```
Route::get('search_offers', static function () {
    $orders = \App\Order::query()->with(['payments', 'tourists']);

    return view('orders', [
        'orders' => $orders->paginate(),
    ]);
});
```

And my orders.blade.php is pretty straightforward

```
<ol>
    @foreach($orders as $order)
    <li>
        {{$order->request_id}}; {{ $order->payments->sum('amount') }}; {{ $order->tourists->implode('fullName', ', ') }}
    </li>
    @endforeach
</ol>
```

However, even the number of queries is very small I have a lot of manipulations with models. I add a custom hook to track all eloquent.* events and in first case there are more than 23_000 of such events.

[image: A lot of manipulations with models]

Then I try to remove the loading of relations so for each order Laravel have to run a separate query to get all order's payments and travellers. I simply did like this in my controller

```
return view('orders', [
    'orders' => \App\Order::query()->paginate(),
]);
```

So, I get more queries but page speed improves and a number of affected models significantly decreased

[image]

To track affected models I add a listner in a AppServiceProvider::boot method and output a AppServiceProvider::$hydratedModels value in a debugbar panel

```
Event::listen('eloquent.*', static function ($event) {
    if (strpos($event, 'eloquent.retrieved') !== false) {
        AppServiceProvider::$hydratedModels++;
    }
});
```

So, my question how it possible that so many models are retrieved even if I display only 15 items. Looks like Laravel somehow get all of them, processed but retruns only those for a required page.

Right now it's not a big deal to run extra queries to fetch some data but I'm wondering maybe I'm doing something wrong and it's possible to load relations but do not cause Laravel to retrieve all models.

Comment: Have you defined the inverse of the relations in the OrderPayment and OrderTourist model? Can you show the queries you get from debugbar in the first case, with 4 queries? You can avoid to post the user load and the session load queries.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. Thanks, @dparoli for a suggestion.

My models have a primary key as UUID. But I did not change a `Model::$keyType` so internally Laravel cast it into an integer and queries look like this.

[image]

Instead of a UUID string, I got integers as an order_id for related records.

**So, I add `protected $keyType = 'string';` and everything starts work as expected.**

PS. Although, I'm wondering how it works before.